# PSR-4 specs and git behavior

Tags: git, autoload, psr-4

I'm trying to wrap my head around why a couple of things have happened to me over the past two days.

I had a folder structure like this:

`includes/bootstrap/Loader.php`

And my namespace for that `Loader.php` file would be something like this:

`App\Bootstrap`

composer was setup for PSR4 with source directory as includes and namespace as `App`.

My code was working PERFECTLY fine locally on my Mac, but when uploaded to a web server(linux) everything broke and it kept spitting that classes weren't found. My searching lead me to the fact that Linux is case sensitive, so I went back and change `bootstrap` folder to `Bootstrap` so new structure was `includes/Bootstrap/Loader.php` everything worked fine in production after that.

1. That was the root cause for it working on my local mac and not on a web server right? The fact that Linux being case sensitive?

Everything currently works fine now, I prefer my namespaces to be like this:

`App\Bootstrap`

I **don't** want my name spaces to be like this:

`App\bootstrap`.

After pushing the code to github I realized it lowercased all folder names! Further searching lead me to the fact that I had to run `it config core.ignorecase false` so it can respect the case of the folder names!

Then I tried pulling down the repo in a totally different directory and terminal showed me this message:

[image]

2. What does it mean by "collided"? There were no files in the folder. Also the version on git is the capitalized folder name version, why did git try to download something different?

I can see that it shows both in the terminal but in the folder it's the actual version which is on github...so I'm just wondering why it showed both versions in the terminal.

3. Would git try to lowercase the repo for someone else on a Mac? How could I prevent these sort of things moving forward? Was it the fact that some folder names in the repo were lowercased before? I read that by default git config ignore case is set to false...why did I have to run it again for git to respect the folder name case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule, Linux file systems are case sensitive and so if you referred to the file as `App\Bootstrap`, then it needs to be in that case in the file system.  So yes, to your first question.

What Git means by "collided" is that your repository has two sets of paths in it: one starting with `include/Bootstrap` and one starting with `include/bootstrap`.  Git is case sensitive, so it treats those paths differently.  However, your Mac is not capable of distinguishing case, so when Git goes to write both sets of paths into the file system, only one of them can be successfully written.

As to the setting `core.ignoreCase`, it is set to reflect what your file system is actually capable of and shouldn't be changed.  The problem is not Git: the problem is that your file system is simply not capable enough to handle this case.  The [Git FAQ explains this in some detail](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#always-modified-files-case).

To remove the duplicates, run `git rm -r --cached includes/bootstrap` and then commit.

You may additionally wish to use a case-sensitive file system in the future, which is an option when formatted in APFS partition, although it is not the default on macOS.  Note that some programs don't handle this gracefully and can cause problems when run on a case-sensitive file system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after I posted the question I went back to github and saw I had two copies on the directories!! After i did some more googling I came across the `git rm -r --cached` command and ran it with `.` so it can correct all directories.

All i wanted was to do some psr4 autoloading and fell into a deep hole of file system incompatibilities